# modify javascript used by window application

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer

I'm modifying the spyder player lyrics pane which uses html and javascript to show the lyrics of the song. Spyder Player is a Windows application, and I'm using it in my Windows 7. The html and javascript files used by the app can be modified. Now the problem is that not all the javascript methods and objects are supported. I made a test and I've found that the `appVersion` returns:

```
4.0 (compatible; MSIE 7.0; Windows NT 6.1; Trident/7.0; SLCC2; .NET CLR 2.0.50727; .NET CLR 3.5.30729; .NET CLR 3.0.30729; Media Center PC 6.0; .NET4.0C; .NET CLR 1.1.4322; .NET4.0E; Tablet PC 2.0)
```

Does That mean it uses IE7? why? and how can i check if a method is supported by this useragent. Does it uses the windows script host? Is there a way to update the javascript engine on my windows. Also if that have to be with IE, I have IE11 installed.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you are talking about this [appVersion](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/NavigatorID.appVersion)

If so, that is set by the browser and you're best off ignoring it.  Some software, using outdated programming models, try to use this information to tell the browsers capabilities.